# How can I visualize validation with predicted arrays using Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, prediction, opencv

```
test_images_path, test_masks_path = get_data_paths(df, openimages_path, "test")
for i in test_images_path:
  img = cv2.imread(epicPath +"/" +i)
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  img = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256),interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
  img = (img-img.min())/(img.max()-img.min())
  norm = cv2.normalize(img, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
  epicPrediction = model.predict(np.expand_dims(norm, axis=0))
  #print(epicPrediction)

val_images_path, val_masks_path = get_data_paths(df, openimages_path, "validation")

for i in val_images_path:
  img = cv2.imread(epicPath +"/" +i)
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  img = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256),interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
  img = (img-img.min())/(img.max()-img.min())
  norm = cv2.normalize(img, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
  epicPrediction = model.predict(np.expand_dims(norm, axis=0))
  print(epicPrediction)
```

As I mentioned in the title, how can i use these series for prediction ? I would like to point out that it is my first experience.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you encode your labels? Integer or categorical?

Comment: As far as i remember, it was categorical.

Answer (score 0):

if your inputs are categorical the predictions are probabilty values of which class the image belongs in. To find out the class do

```
class_index=np.argmax(epicPrediction) this will give you and index into the list of classes. I assume you have that stored somewhere . For example if your classes are stored in an ordered list like say [dog, cat, mouuse,etc] then the index points to the class.
```